# java.lang.Object cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, scala

I call a function in the stream, that expression a predicate as return value:

```
KTable<String, String> store = source
.filter((key, value) -> Path.store().apply(value));
```

The `Path.store` is written in `Scala` and looks as following:

```
def store: String => Boolean =
  (v) =>
    encode(v).error.isEmpty
```

and the compiler complains:

```
[error]     java.lang.Object cannot be converted to boolean
[error]     .filter((key, value) -> Path.store().apply(value));
```

Do I have to convert to primitive?

Comment: This is probably `store()` returns `scala.Boolean` not `java.lang.Boolean`. One way could be to convert to Java Boolean. example `def store: String => java.lang.Boolean =`

Comment: why do you have `->` arrow inside the `filter` condition? Shouldn't it be `=>`?

Comment: also `Path.store` expects one `String` argument and not clear to me why you write `Path.store()`.

Comment: What is the source? Please show show that.

Comment: `Path.store()` is written in Scala and `.filter((key, value) -> Path.store().apply(value))` is in Java.

Comment: How to convert `Boolean` Scala into Java?

Comment: I see, sorry. Should clean my glasses :)

Comment: I've deleted my answer since you have suggested a proper solution yourself and actually I learned something from your question, not vice versa :)

Comment: But anyway thanks a lot :-)

Comment: `Boolean.box` will box a `scala.Boolean` into a `java.lang.Boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see `java.lang.Object` as the result of `apply` in Java is originated from the richer type system of Scala. [`Function1[-T1, +R]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) is covariant in its return type, which cannot be expressed on the JVM in a typesafe way that Java can also interpret, so the return type of the `apply` is going to be `Object`.

You need to cast it back to `Boolean` (I hope I did not make a syntactic mistake):

```
source.filter((key, value) -> ((Boolean)Path.store().apply(value)).booleanValue());
```